# In angularjs, how can I make the same functionality available both to config functions and controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I make the same functionality available both to config functions and controllers? I've run into this problem twice:

1. A service which is a collection of utility functions specific to my app. But services are not available to `app.config` functions.
2. Using ui-router, states and routes are configured in an `app.config` function but I would like for the same data to be available in controllers so that I can dynamically generate menus.

I could solve both situations by putting the functions or route data in the global `window` scope outside of angular, but it seems like there ought to be a better way. Something like how ui-router defines `$state` and `$stateProvider` except I want them to be the same.

Comment: global functions maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Use a provider that returns the same function for the Provider and the actual service.

```
module.provider('GlobalFuncs', function ($resourceProvider) {
    var service = this;
    this.funcOne = function(value) {
        // Do Something
    };

    this.funcTwo = function(value) {
        // Do Something
    };

    this.$get = function() {
        return service;
    };

});
```

From a config do:

```
module.config(function(GlobalFuncsProvider) {
});
```

From a controller

```
module.controller('ctrl', function(GlobalFuncs) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Services are available to controllers and factories are available in the config step. Both services and factories are a special type of a [provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). Using the base provider type, we can define APIs for both the service and the factory.

```
app.provider('testService', function(){

  this.providerMethod = function(){ 
    return 'providerMethod'; 
  };

  this.$get = function(){
    return {
      serviceMethod: function(){ 
        return 'serviceMethod'; 
      }
    };
  }

});

app.config(function(testServiceProvider){
  console.log('config', testServiceProvider.providerMethod());
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, testService) {
  console.log('controller', testService.serviceMethod());
});
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MSjiB4DxPp6cRD91x17J?p=preview)

But that exposes two different APIs. If we want them to be the same, we can do this:

```
app.provider('testService', function(){

  this.providerMethod = function(){ 
    return 'providerMethod'; 
  };

  this.$get = function(){
    return this;
  }

});

app.config(function(testServiceProvider){
  console.log('config', testServiceProvider.providerMethod());
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, testService) {
  console.log('controller', testService.providerMethod());
});
```

Comment: Balls ... beaten to the punch by less than a minute

Comment: @Enzey yeah sorry I should've answered the question before posting it but I clicked the wrong button